# Can't load txt filein python

Tags: python, txt

I don't know why but the code i'm going to show you always returns me an empty list.
Can you please tell me why?

```
def load_map(path):
f = open(path + '.txt', 'r')
data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')
f.close()
game_map = []
for row in game_map:
    game_map.append(list(row))
return game_map
```

Comment: Did you mean `for row in data:`?

Comment: You ard not using data.

Comment: Your code has clear indentation errors. What's less clear is where the indents are properly supposed to be. Please [edit] to fix these Python syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
game_map = []
for row in game_map:
```

initializes an empty list, then iterates over it.

```
def load_map(path):
    with open(path + '.txt') as f:
        return list(f.read().split("\n"))
```

would do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

'''for row in game_map''' doesn't do any iterations because game_map is empty.

You probably want '''for row in data'''